# How to install a Magento 2 theme manually with php (cgi-fcgi) - Error

Tags: php, magento, themes

I am trying to install a theme for Magento 2. I have uploaded and replaced the app and pub folder in the root directory for the site.

I have connected with SSH and ran the following code:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade –keep-generated
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I then get the following error:

```
bin/magento must be run as a CLI application
```

The version of php on the server is su-php:

```
PHP 5.4.42 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jun 16 2015 14:54:07)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd., and
with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

I have found that the issue is the version of php - php(cgi-fcgi) and is should be php(cgi) however my hosts tell me that this cannot be changed. Any idea how I can install a theme with these parameters.

Comment: you are running under CGI sapi, while as the error describes , magento needs CLI sapi

Comment: I honestly do now know the difference and from what I have been told this isnt something I can change. My host providers fully support magento and I am using one of their installations of it. Do you know of any possible work around?

Comment: So I see the difference between CGI and CLI. I am running the code through Mac terminal (which should be CLI) but using SSH, which I am guessing is CGI?

Comment: as you said, it's all in your host provider hands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue.  My PHP was running under CLI mode, and it was somehow changed to cgi-fcgi mode.  Is there a way to switch back to cli mode?

I have tried reinstalling the php-cli but no luck...

Comment: After much research, I've found out that you need to add 

source /opt/cpanel/your php folder/enable intoto /etc/bashrc and php -v results in showing cli.

try running source /opt/cpanel/your php folder/enable first to see if it works.